# Proving commutativity of add, Take 2

Tags: logic, proof, isabelle, theorem

This question is a follow up to the following question [isabelle proving commutativity for add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815932/isabelle-proving-commutativity-for-add), my followup was too long to be a comment. The problem as stated was to show the commutativity of the add function defined as follows:

```
fun add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
  "add 0 n = n" |
  "add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"
```

Trying

```
theorem "add m n = add n m"
apply(induct_tac m)
apply(auto)
```

gets stuck (on the inductive case) because of a missing lemma. I got curious about this problem, and was exploring alternative (albeit less efficient) way of proving it. Suppose we defined the Lemma

```
lemma Lemma1 [simp]: "add n (Suc 0) = Suc n
```

which Isabelle can automatically prove by induction
Then the inductive step is to prove

```
Suc (add k m) = add m (Suc k)
```

which we could do by hand as follows

```
   Suc (add k m)
=  Suc (add m k) by the IH
=  add (add m k) (Suc 0) by Lemma1 <--
=  add m (add k (Suc 0)) by associativity (already proved)
=  add m (Suc k) by the Lemma1 -->
```

However, Isabelle is unable to prove this, and it appears the simplifier is stuck at the 2nd line.  However, using the more obvious

```
lemma Lemma2 [simp]: "add m (Suc n) = Suc (add m n)"
```

instead of Lemma1, the proof succeeds. It seems to be able to use  Lemma2 in both directions but not the Lemma1 I defined above.
Does anyone know why? I feel like I am overlooking something obvious somewhere..

Remarks: I realize the simplifier actually only applies definitions etc in one direction but uses heuristics to try and reduce both sides of the equation to the same term

Comment: To make it easier to help you without firing up Isabelle, can you also paste the proof state a the point where proofs are failing, e.g. where you say “gets stuck because of a missing lemma”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma2 is not used in both directions, as you can see when you try to do the proof manually with `subst` steps:

```
theorem commutativity2: 
"add n m = add m n"
apply (induct n)
apply (subst Lemma0)
apply (subst add.simps(1))
apply (rule refl)

(* ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ add (Suc n) m = add m (Suc n) *)
apply (subst add.simps(2))
(* ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ Suc (add n m) = add m (Suc n) *)
apply (erule ssubst)
(* ⋀n. Suc (add m n) = add m (Suc n) *)
apply (subst Lemma2)
(* ⋀n. Suc (add m n) = Suc (add m n) *)
apply (rule refl)
done
```

It is just working on the right hand side of the goal-equation, but still using Lemma1 from left to right.

If you want to do the proof as in your manual proof you can also easily do it in Isabelle:

```
theorem commutativity: 
"add m n = add n m"
proof (induct m)
  show "add 0 n = add n 0" using Lemma0 by simp
next case (Suc k)
  have      "add (Suc k) n 
                 = Suc (add k n)" by simp
  also have "... = Suc (add n k)" using Suc.hyps by simp
  also have "... = add (add n k) (Suc 0)" using Lemma1 by simp
  also have "... = add n (add k (Suc 0))" using associativity by simp
  also have "... = add n (Suc k)" using Lemma1 by simp
  finally show ?case .
qed
```

EDIT:

A manual proof showing why this does not work with Lemma1: In the first rewrite Lemma 1 has to be used from right to left (using `[symmetric]`).

```
theorem commutativity3: 
"add n m = add m n"
apply (induct n)
apply (subst Lemma0)
apply (subst add.simps(1))
apply (rule refl)

(* ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ add (Suc n) m = add m (Suc n) *)
apply (subst Lemma1[symmetric]) back
(*  ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ add (Suc n) m = add m (add n (Suc 0)) *)
apply (subst associativity)
(* ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ add (Suc n) m = add (add m n) (Suc 0) *)
apply (subst Lemma1)
(* ⋀n. add n m = add m n ⟹ add (Suc n) m = Suc (add m n) *)
apply (erule subst)
(* ⋀n. add (Suc n) m = Suc (add n m) *)
apply (subst add.simps(2))
(* ⋀n. Suc (add n m) = Suc (add n m) *)
apply (rule refl)
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry I mis-spoke when I said it was using Lemma2 in "both directions". However, what it does do is use its heuristic to simplify the RHS of the equation (ie "add m (Suc n)") in the 3rd step. This is what I meant by my comment about the simplifier rewriting one side or the other. My question is why can't it do the same thing (ie choose either the LHS or RHS) to prove it when given Lemma1 instead of Lemma2?

Comment: If you try to do the proof manually with Lemma1, you will see that Lemma1 has to be used from right to left once. I have edited my post to show this. I don't think the rewriter distinguished between LHS and RHS of the goal. It just tries to find the LHS of the equation in the goal and replaces it with the RHS of the equation.

Comment: ISWYM. I think that if I could instead prove 
    lemma lemma1' [simp]: "Suc n = add n (Suc 0)" 
Then the proof would go through. However, the prover gets stuck on 
   lemma Lemma0': "n = add n 0"
I need to be able to direct the prover (in this case the auto prover starts expanding the definition of add instead of applying the IH. Where can I find out more about the apply steps you did above, and the kinds of arguments you can supply to it? I didn't see anything about it in the tutorial